# WCF Middleware/Interceptor for returning custom response earlier

Tags: c#, wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

**What i want to achieve:**

I want to controll all calls to WCF methods and add some validation. If the validation fails then i want the method to return earlier with a custom response of the same type with the method return type.

How can i achieve this in central place without having to add the validation check in every method?

Here is the pseudocode:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Microsoft.WCF.Documentation
{
  [ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://microsoft.wcf.documentation")]
  public interface ISampleService
  {
    [OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern=true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginGetCustomerInfo(GetCustomerInfoRequest request, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    GetCustomerInfoResponse EndGetCustomerInfo(IAsyncResult result);

    [OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern=true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginGetProductDetails(GetProductDetailsRequest request, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    GetProductDetailsResponse EndGetProductDetails(IAsyncResult result);
  }

  public class SampleService : ISampleService
  {
    public IAsyncResult BeginGetCustomerInfo(GetCustomerInfoRequest request, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("BeginGetCustomerInfo called with: \"{0}\"", request);
      //...
    }

    public GetCustomerInfoResponse EndGetCustomerInfo(IAsyncResult r)
    {
        //...
        return new GetCustomerInfoResponse();
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginGetProductDetails(GetProductDetailsRequest request, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("BeginGetProductDetails called with: \"{0}\"", request);
      //...
    }

    public GetProductDetailsResponse EndGetProductDetails(IAsyncResult r)
    {
        //...
        return new GetProductDetailsResponse();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WCF message interceptor. A message interceptor allows you to intercept incoming and outgoing messages in a WCF service.

You need to add a class which implements the [IDispatchMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) interface, let's say `ValidationInterceptor`. your validation logic should be implemented in `AfterReceiveRequest` method.

And a class which implements `Attribute, IServiceBehavior`, you can write your logic in [ApplyDispatchBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.applydispatchbehavior?view=netframework-4.8.1) method like the below.

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{
    foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase channelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
    {
        ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = channelDispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;
        if (channelDispatcher != null)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new ValidationInterceptor());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use like this

```
[ValidationInterceptor]
public IAsyncResult BeginGetCustomerInfo(GetCustomerInfoRequest request, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BeginGetCustomerInfo called with: \"{0}\"", request);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By implementing [IDispatchMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-and-modify-messages-on-the-service) interface and use AfterReceiveRequest and BeforeSendReply this two methods to receive requests and logic operation before the request is sent.

Under AfterReceiveReply there is the [ValidateMessageBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors) method, which wraps a validation XmlReader around the body content subtree of the passed message like this:

```
object IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    if (validateRequest)
    {
        // inspect the message. If a validation error occurs,
        // the thrown fault exception bubbles up.
        ValidateMessageBody(ref request, true);
    }
    return null;
}
```